# change datasource after initialization

Tags: spring-data

I have a spring-boot 1.5.10 backend using a file based h2 database.  I already use

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datasource.h2")
@Bean
public DataSource getDataSource()
```

to dynamically set the database URL and credentials at start up.

Now I need to support a change to set the datasource, based on user input (so after the server has started completely).

my plan is to

- set up the datasource to a tmp location initially where an empty db is created,
- copy the correct db file from the place the user specifies into the correct location
- update the datasource to point to this.
- (and subsequently delete the tmp file if I can unlock it.)

Can I update the datasource after the server has initialized?

AbstractRoutingDatasource is supported from Spring 2.0.1, so not available to me